# Cannot find namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: angular, bing-maps, angular9

I'm working with Angular 9 and I'm trying to integrate BingMaps,

So I get this compilation error:

```
src/app/dashboard/pages/infos-generale/infos/infos.component.ts:33:8 

- error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Microsoft'.

33   map: Microsoft.Maps.Map;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have just to add bingmaps into recognized types in tsconfig.app.json:

**tsconfig.app.json :**

```
   "compilerOptions": {
     "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
     "types": [
+      "bingmaps"
     ]
```

If types is specified, only packages listed will be included.

So in our case, This tsconfig.json file will only include ./node_modules/@types/bingmaps. 
Other packages under node_modules/@types/* will not be included.
A types package is a folder with a file called index.d.ts or a folder with a package.json that has a types field.